# Liquibase changelog does not carry the column position or 'AFTER column_name'

Tags: mysql, liquibase

To generate a database change log for a table alteration, I use Liquibase. But liquibase change logs doesn't carry specific positions of column name.

The following change set was generated through liquibase

```
<changeSet author="Nevil" id="234324324324">
    <addColumn tableName="request">
        <column name="revenue" type="DECIMAL(10,2)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Suppose if I want column `revenue` to go after column `id` in `request` table, liquibase doesn't take a note of the AFTER clause in alter table commend. In effect I cannot do it with liquibase. Any solution friends ?

Answer (score 1):

I was told that one cannot rely on column order when processing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

One should always specify the columns required:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM my_table;
```

Following this advice makes the column order within the table a cosmetic concern.

I'm completely open to correction, but I don't think all databases support adding columns mid-table.